# How to display the number of rows and columns in a matrix with an even number of 1s?

Tags: java, matrix

I wrote a code that displays a matrix filled with 0s and 1s. My problem is that I don't know how to calculate and display the number of rows and columns that have an even number of 1s. For example a six by six matrix with 3 rows of 2 1s and 1 row with 2 1s.

Display : Number of rows with an even number of 1s : 3
          Number of columns with an even number of 1s: 1

I know that there has to be a code that uses mod to determine whether it's even, but I don't know where to put it in the code. Here is what I have.

```
public class Matrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][]matrix = new int [6][6];

        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
                matrix[row][col] = (int)(Math.random()*2);
            }

        }           

        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
                System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " "); 
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}


1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 1 1
```

Number of rows with an even number of 1s: 3
Number of columns with a even number of 1s: 5

Comment: How about showing us some output.  Both what you expect and what this code is giving you.

Comment: A number is even if `number % 2 == 0`.

Comment: I did say what I expect, I want the matrix to display while counting the even number of 1s in the rows and columns of the matrix. What I have right now is just the matrix being displayed. Sorry, I'm not too sure as to how to put what I expect in my post.

Comment: @user81218 put it in like you put in the code. Indent the output in four spaces, and then type what you expect it to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
int evenRowCount = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    int rowCount = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
        rowCount += matrix[row][col];
    }
    if (rowCount % 2 == 0) {
       evenRowCount++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of rows with an even number of 1s:" + evenRowCount);

int evenColCount = 0;
for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
    int colCount = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
        colCount += matrix[row][col];
    }
    if (colCount % 2 == 0) {
       evenColCount++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of cols with an even number of 1s:" + evenColCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of 1's in a given column. You're loops look pretty good, but include another loop that goes over every cell in a row and adds up the values (no need to check if it's a one, since 0 doesn't add to a count).

To figure out if the value is even, use the modulus (remainder operator), which is `%`. Basically, this operator works by dividing a number by another number, but instead of giving the quotient it gives the remainder, as a n integer. So `5 % 2 == 1` is a true statement in Java. You can use `count % 2 == 0` in your code to figure out if a count is even.

Then use your current loops to print out the even rows.

Answer (score 0):

A nice easy way is to loop through the rows/columns and have a boolean flip for every encountered 1.  Start off the boolean true because nothing is even, and the first 1 you encounter will flip it to false, second to true, and so on...

```
public static int evenColumns(int[][] matrix)
{
    int columns = 0;
    for(int[] ints : matrix)
    {
        boolean even = true;
        for(int i : ints)
            if(i == 1)
                even = !even;
        if(even)
            columns++;
    }
    return columns;
}

public static int evenRows(int[][] matrix)
{
    int rows = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < matrix[0].length; row++)
    {
        boolean even = true;
        for(int[] ints : matrix)
            if(ints[row] == 1)
                even = !even;
        if(even)
            rows++;
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Another, more common approach, would be to find the number of 1's in the row/column and then check that to see if it's even/odd with `ones % 2 == 0`, `ones & 1 == 0`, and other similar checks